# Is it possible to reuse a WKInterfaceGroup?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

Is it possible on WatchKit to reuse a WKInterfaceGroup in let's say the Main WKInterfaceController and the Glance WKInterfaceController?

Is there like an individual WKInterfaceGroup IB Document like there is for UIView?  Or a way to export / programmatically recreate...

Or is my only option Copy-Paste?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Only copy paste for now. Frustrating, right?

Comment: Thanks Brian for confirming.  Yeah, I bet in the near future they remedy this.